# Returning pointer to structure in socket programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, opendir

In one of my projects an `opendir()` call in a client program is intervened using LD_PRELOAD and sent to a file sever for its processing (I do some logging in the server before calling `opendir()`). Thus the call passes through a socket. Now how do I return the pointer to a DIR structure (which is returned from the `opendir()` call) from the server to the client through the socket. Do I convert it to string and send?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Client and server have different address spaces, even if they are on the same machine. Therefore you cannot possibly send a pointer through a socket and expect it to do anything meaningful at the other end.

One valid way of doing such a thing would be to place the structure in a shared memory section, and send an *offset* into the shared memory region. Obviously that will also only work if client and server are on the same physical machine.
EDIT:
And, even though this will work for reading the data, you should (obviously) beware of calling functions like `closedir` or otherwise freeing the memory from the other process. Such things almost certainly mean terribly bad luck (in the sense of: now you're going to die).

In the "normal" case of client and server being on different machines, there is no way you can do such a thing at all. You can send string data or serialized data just fine of course, but never pointers or anything similar.